# When should the AssemblyVersion be changed? When it should not be?

Tags: c#, .net, version, versioning, .net-assembly

The framework application I work on exposes lots of APIs which are consumed by other modules/applications which are integrated in our framework. Current Product Version of my application is 2.1.1800.0. We started with 2.0.0.0. However, we never changed the 'AssemblyVersion' of all the assemblies we have; it's still 2.0.0.0.

Now we have migrated our application to .NET 4.6 and upgraded our product version to 3.0.0.0 since it's major upgrade. As far as APIs are concerned, we do not have any breaking changes. But we are changing the major version of the product because the whole application is compiled on new .NET Framework.

**In this case, shall I upgrade `AssemblyVersion` of all assemblies too? 
What is the general guideline or exepert's opinion when it comes to handling assembly version in such applications?**

No assembly is strongly named. But I know that some modules refer to them within configuration files using exact version number as given in following example. So change in the assembly version will force them to update their relevant configuration too.

```
<section name="AppFramework" type="AppFramework.Client.ConfigReader, AppFramework.Client,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null"/>
```

Comment: Meh, the client programmer will have very little trouble discovering that he needs to target 4.6 or higher to use your library.  He doesn't need a version number to discover this, nor does "3.0.0.0" give him any decent hint that this is what he needs to do.  "4.6.0.0" might do that, sort of.  A sane way to use version numbers is to signal the client programmer that he needs (or might consider) to change his code.  Read up on "semantic versioning".

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment. Documentation can inform others about changes. I am not saying that other programmers will know about .NET version they need by looking at version number of my assembly. My question is  : 
"If there are no breaking changes in the APIs (or really big enhancement anyway) and my change of version numbers is going to force other programmers to take some (though little) extra efforts, then is it advisable to change the version number of my assemblies just because they are compiled on newer .NET Framework? Is there any guideline or advise about the same?"